# How to show a text area and button when user clicks a button, but its not a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this form, I want when the button is clicked by user, it shows textarea and button below the button that clicked by user. Much like invoice or notes in advance. In the textarea, user can write any note or revision, just plain text. This is example of the button code `<button type="button" id="revision" onclick="myFunction()" class>Revision</button>` And this is 
 the javascript

```js
<script> 
function myFunction() { 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = <textarea style="resize: none; width: 400px; height: 100px;" type="text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>;}
</script>
```

I tried it but the button didn't show the textarea.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `append` function to insert dom elements dynamically.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.classList = ['form-control'];
  textarea.rows = 4;
  document.getElementById("demo").append(textarea);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">
Add Text Area
</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following would do what you want but it can be done in another way

```js
function myFunction() { 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<textarea style="resize: none; width: 400px; height: 100px;" type="text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>`;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show TextArea</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

What you could do is hide text area and show it when button is clicked;

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show TextArea</button>
<textarea id="myTextarea" style="resize: none; width: 400px; height: 100px; display: none;" type="text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
function myFunction() {
 if(true)
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
 else
 document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```